# Unable to retrieve the previous value when updating

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

I just started to convert my project from MongoDB to PostgreSQL by using `sequelize` and `sequelize-typescript` and have bumped into a problem:

I made with MongoDB an upsert method which simply uses `findOneAndUpdate`. It finds a single user by its userId, if none is found it creates one otherwise it updates it with an object. The returned `value` is the record before being updated. Easy right ?

```
  upsert: async (userId: string, obj: Partial<UserModel>) => {
    const { value } = await this._users.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: userId },
      { $set: obj },
      { upsert: true }
    );
    return value!;
  },
```

Now when I want to use `sequelize`, first I have to use `findByPk` (which is the userId) since `findOrCreate` is fairly slow (my app crashed multiple times already because of timeout) then if a record is found I update it with an object otherwise I use `<Model>.create`. The thing is that `<Model>.update` does not return the previous value, `.previous()` sends empty brackets back.

Here is the method I am currently working with:

```
upsert: async (userId: string, obj: Partial<User>): Promise<User | null> => {
  const user = await User.findByPk(userId);

  if (user) {
    console.log(1, user);

    if (user.login !== obj.login) {
      const test = await user.update(obj);
      console.log(2, test);
      console.log(3, test.previous());
    }

    return user;
  }

  return await User.create(obj)
    .catch(() => null)
    .finally(() => null);
},
```

This is the console output:

[image]

Am I missing a key point here? Or is it not even possible? I am digging in the docs and overall on Google and I found nothing about that

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get previous values from `update`. You need to store `user` props somewhere before calling `update`:

```js
const oldUser = user.get({ plain: true });

if (user.login !== obj.login) {
  const test = await user.update(obj);
  console.log(2, test);
  console.log(3, oldUser);
}
```

As for `previous()` it returns original or previously saved values before any `set` calls and until `save` will be called.